# Wubi installer stuck at expanding

Tags: wubi

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 on windows 7. After running the wubi installer it downloaded the files but now the setup is just showing expanding and its been over 2 hours.
Any solution ?

Comment: It could just be very, very slow. What kind of CPU do you have?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to mount iso in daemon-tools, that may cause many problems. Best way is to download the iso and WUBI installer. Place it in same folder on Windows and run WUBI.

WUBI installer has built-in iso-check so corrupt iso is not possible to pass. In some cases, WUBI automatically download 64bit version if you have CPU 64bit capable.
That is a major problem if you have low RAM.

So, download the iso, download WUBI instaler, put them in same folder (*do not mount ISO in daemon*) and run WUBI as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I also had this problem. 
I "fixed it" (more like a work-around) by downloading Ubuntu 11.10 iso image ([See the Oneiric download page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/)), mounting it with Daemon tools, installing it inside windows using the built-in wubi, and then updated to 12.04 through the Ubuntu updater. It's a bummer and takes time, but at least it worked.

I hope they fix Wubi ASAP.

Emannxx

PS: Don't download Ubuntu 12.04 iso image as it doesn't come with "Wubi installer" anymore.

Comment: You can make live usb/cd if you already have iso image. Just boot cd/usb and install from there.